# Write an array in specific column by Pandas to_excel

Tags: python, pandas

`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` documentation says column is  optional Columns to write, but I'm wrong, how should the specific column (e.g. column J) be defined?

```
import pandas as pd
my_array = [0 for i in range(len(data))]
pd_array = pd.DataFrame(my_array)
pd_array.to_excel(r'C:\Users\my_dir\SandBox.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2', columns = 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, `startcol` was the answer!

```
pd_array.to_excel(r'C:\Users\my_dir\SandBox.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2', startcol= 8)
```